# How to replace a string in a dataframe column with another in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a dataframe called **df_cv** with column that contains this string **_log**.
I would like to delete **_log** from the name of each column in a dataframe
So i didlike this :

```
modify_cols=[]
for c in df_cv.columns:
    if c.find("_log") != -1:
        modify_cols.append(c)

for c in modify_cols:
     c = c.replace('_log',' ')
```

But it didn't work , there is no error message but the comluns name doesn't change.

Any idea please to help me?

Thanks

Comment: But what do you do with c variable after? With current code it will be garbage collected.

Comment: do you mean `df_cv.columns=df_cv.columns.str.strip('_log')` ??

Comment: @anky_91 - rather not, a bit dangerous, it remove all values from end `_, l, o, g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `list-comprehension`:

```
df_cv.columns = [i.replace("_log","") for i in df_cv.columns]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df_cv = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1','col2_log','1_log'])
df_cv.columns=df_cv.columns.str.replace('_log', '')
print (df_cv)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1, col2, 1]
Index: []
```

Comment: Only answer using pandas methods. Should be top answer.

Comment: @jezrael  thank you very much, as usual you help me. Il apreciate!!

Comment: @Nasri - You are welcome, some problem with solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should collect results in a collection, or at least process them

```
modified_cols=[]
for c in modify_cols:
     modified_cols.append(c.replace('_log',' '))
```

Or shorter version, using [list comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python):

```
my_list = [c.replace('_log',' ') for c in df_cv.columns if c.find('_log')!=-1]
```

Otherwise you will lost each `c` variable after each loop block.

Answer (score 0):

`=` makes the reference to `c` becomes a new string, but the string referenced by the `modify_cols` is still the original. and because of string is immutable， so you can not do like this：

```py
s = [['a_log'], ['b_log']]
for i in s:
    # i reference to the mutable list
    i[0] = i[0].replace('_log', '')
# now s is [['a'], ['b']]
```

you can use list comprehension:

```
modify_cols = [c.replace('_log',' ') for c in modify_cols]
```

Comment: this focused on explaining why there is no change.